# Passing structure as an argument in function

Tags: c, structure

I have a question about passing arguments in function. Like I discovered that I can pass arguments of structure in two ways:

**First**:

```
name_t* foo(name_t* foo)
{
    //do some changes with structure
    return foo->something
}
```

**Second**:

```
name_t foo(name_t foo)
{
    //do some changes with structure
    return foo.something
}
```

What is difference between this approaches?

How does it put in memory?

Whether there are underwater rocks when I use **first** approach with **second** in the same function? For example, when two arguments passed in same function and first would equal to second and vice versa.

Like that:

```
name_t* foo(name_t* foo, name_t foo2)
{
    //do some changes with structures
    foo->something = foo2.something;
    return foo;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is the `something` member a `name_t` or `name_t*`? It seems to have changed between the two versions of the code.

Comment: Maybe you meant `return foo;` in both cases?

Comment: for sure it is impossible a `name_t` contains a `name_t` (not a pointer to), so `name_t foo(name_t foo) { return foo.something;}`has no sense. Bad idea too to hide the function name by the param name

Comment: Please correct your question editing it, it is not consistent => impossible to answer you without making (may be wrong) assumption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **First** version passes a pointer to the caller's structure. Any changes made through the pointer will affect the caller's structure.

The **Second** version passes a copy of the caller's structure, because C is a call-by-value language. Any changes only affect the local copy, not the caller's structure. However, it's a shallow copy; if the structure contains pointer to other structures, they are not copied recursively, and changes to those referenced structures will affect the originals.

The last example should be fine. `foo2` is a copy of the caller's structure, you can make changes to it without affecting the caller. Then you can modify the caller's structure when you assign through the `foo` pointer. There's no aliasing problem since one is a copy.

Comment: note it is impossible a `name_t` contains a `name_t` (not a pointer to)  => second definition `name_t foo(name_t foo) { return foo.something;}`has no sense. Bad idea too to hide the function name by the param name

Comment: But it's OK if it's `name_t *something` as in a linked list.

Comment: because *something* is a `name_t *` the assignment in the third definition can create a memory leak , and the pointer is shared after, with that implies

Comment: yes, but this is not consistent with the second function signature (return value type)

Comment: I think we're not really supposed to take these types and members literally, he simplified the examples too much.

Comment: the OP really needs to improve/correct the question, there is very few and that few is wrong, so if we cannot read literally the few being given where to go ^^

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the vary important points raised in above comments (parameter name hides function name, and inconsistent function signature in first and second clips).

I would like to offer that you should consider the physical size of your structure when deciding how to create and pass instances of structures:

```
typedef struct name_t {
  char title[256];
  int something;
} name_t;

int my_function(name_t n) {
    // this function cannot change the sender's copy of n
    return strlen(n.title);
}

int my-by_ref(name_t * n) {
    // this function has the ability to change n and reflect changes back
    // do work
    return ...
}
```

On a system that represents `int` as 4 bytes, each instance of this structure will occupy 260 bytes.

```
name_t person = {"John Doe", 1}; // 260 bytes on stack
int len_title = my_function(person); // pushes another 260 bytes onto the stack
int result = my_by_ref(&person); // pushes the number of bytes a pointer takes 
...
```

This is a contrived example, but sending by reference will require the CPU to copy the address of person (typically 8 bytes, but depends on you OS), rather than 260 bytes.  That can add up if this structure needs to be processed frequently.

There are many more efficient ways to implement such a task, each of which carries certain responsibilities, such as making sure you do not return pointers to data that will go out of scope after the function completes, which are outside the scope of your question.